# How to disable the cancel button in rdesktop?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, thin-client

I work in IT for a community college and we're currently trying to re-purpose some yesteryear machines as thin clients.

I'm pretty much there, where rdesktop opens up the terminal server login screen beautifully.  The missing element is that the kids/users can still hit cancel and get into the linux environment.  How can I disable that functionality?

Right now it runs: $rdesktop 0.0.0.0 -u "" -g 1280x1024 -f

It's glorious.  Really, it is.  But it can be circumvented, which we simply cannot have!

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: You can always recompile the rdesktop app and remove/hide the cancel button.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution.  Well, there goes a year of my life!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say "circumvented", but if you mean that users could hit "cancel" and end up dropping back to a terminal, then nothing stops you from placing `rdesktop` in a while loop...  Here is an example:

```
while true; do rdesktop 0.0.0.0 -u "" -g 1280x1024 -f; done
```

It doesn't get much simpler than that...

Also, I've used this method before, and there is NO time for a user to hit CTRL+C between `rdesktop` instances if done right (use the `rdesktop` while loop INSIDE `xinit`, do not create an `xinit` while loop, or there will be time for CTRL+C).